# How can I stop script execution if insert value is null and set value if not null?

Tags: mysql

I have tried to use Case and SET NOEXEC ON but get the following errors:

> Syntax Error: unexpected 'SET' (set)
>
> Syntax Error: missing 'closing parenthesis'

`INSERT INTO tag (table, repr, tag, value)
    SELECT 'product' AS table,
           @Id AS repr,
           'product_code' AS tag,
           CASE @Code

             WHEN NOT null THEN @Code
             ELSE SET NOEXEC ON
           END AS value`

@Id and @Code are declared parameters in the script

Comment: Mysql and sql server are two different products.

Comment: The answer provided by jd_ below does not "stop" execution when your variable it is NULL, it simply does not attempt the insert.  Depending on your business and use cases, you may want to implement some logging and/or handling of instances when a NULL is received.  ie: If there is more to the body of the script, you may want to ensure a rollback occurs so that partial data is not still updated by this script when you "skip" this insert.

Comment: This is for mysql @Shadow

Comment: Yes there is more insert statements if value is not null, hence I want to stop script execution if null @user7396598

Comment: @DBNewbie well, there is no such functionality in mysql. Noexec is for ms sql server.

Comment: @DBNewbie your entire syntax in the question follows ms sql syntax, including the use of @ in the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOEXEC ON -- is a command and not a value, so you can't use it in insert statment.
```

try below sql (ms - sql)

```
if(@Code is not null)
begin
INSERT INTO tag (table, repr, tag, value)
    SELECT 'product' AS table,
           @Id AS repr,
           'product_code' AS tag,
           @Code AS value
end
```

Comment: This is for MySQL @jd_